# Elastic Beanstalk Custom VPC - This configuration does not contain a load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-application-load-balancer

I've setup a custom VPC with a Load Balancer, when I create an Elastic Beanstalk application I choose "Configure more options".
I then choose my custom VPC under Network settings, but the "Load balancer" setting section shows "This configuration does not contain a load balancer."
And I am unable to choose one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before selecting any configuration settings choose preset "Custom configuration", this will allow you to set the Load balancer.
If you set the Network configuration first then preset "Custom configuration" is automatically selected but the Load balancer section is not available.